# How do I create auto combine URLs in Excel when i input the text?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, hyperlink, excel-online

```
URLs Sample
A:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?a=""
B:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?b=""
C:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?c=""
     A             B            C
1 AA10002143    BBANZIEC    CC123415
2 AA21001234    BBCSKAUD    CC123556 
3 AA11231214    BBKLKFSH    CC134564
```

I need a formula that combines a cell's value and text string that will complete a URL within the `HYPERLINK` function. I tried the following formula, but it won't work:

```
=HYPERLINK([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?c="]Sheet1!C1&["],C1)
```

Any help is gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=HYPERLINK("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?c="&Sheet1!C1, Sheet1!C1)
'convert spaces in url to %20
=HYPERLINK("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?c="&substitute(Sheet1!C1, " ", "%20"), Sheet1!C1)
```

Comment: A url uses %20 (hex for 32dec) instead of a space although most modern browser have overhead that compensates. I'll add an alternative.

Comment: @Jepped +1, still not work, I tryed add    &"%20"  after the substitute, but seem like cannot add anything on the end of the link